# Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, executable, google-chrome-extension

*How to start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?*

So basically I have an executable file which does the job when you launch it. I need to be able to start it without a window (it is a console application) and pass the current URL to it in an argument,

Comment: If there is a god then Google will never allow anyone to do this under any circumstances.

Comment: Question has a good pagerank on google, so for anyone who's looking for answer to this question this might be helpful. There is an extension in google chrome marketspace to do exactly that:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a program from a Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917543/execute-a-program-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @msangel Since the question you mention is posterior to this one it should be considered as the duplicate.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Previously, you would do this through [NPAPI plugins](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi).

However, [Google is now phasing out NPAPI for Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html), so the preferred way to do this is using the [native messaging API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging). The external application would have to register a native messaging host in order to exchange messages with your application.

Comment: I actually think you can, using FileIO: https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable

Answer (score 28):

You can't launch arbitrary commands, but if your users are willing to go through some extra setup, you can use [custom protocols](https://web.archive.org/web/20210601082308/https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-?mobile_site=true).

E.g. you have the users set things up so that `some-app://` links start "SomeApp", and then in `my-awesome-extension` you open a tab pointing to `some-app://some-data-the-app-wants`, and you're good to go!

Comment: The link has expired.

Comment: Archived page for the dead "custom protocols" link: https://web.archive.org/web/20210601082308/https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-?mobile_site=true

Answer (score 4):

[Native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-host)

### Chrome-extensions

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"  //  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/
  ]
  // ...
}
```

### Host

Add schema

```
@echo off
:: If you add "/f" then you can force write.
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application" ^
 /ve /t REG_SZ ^
 /d "%~dp0Mymanifest.json"
```

```
// Mymanifest.json
{
  "name": "com.my_company.my_application",
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "relative_dir/my.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://nbjjflbnekmabedahdolabcpahfjojjb/"
  ]
}
```

[chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendNativeMessage)

example:

```js
// your.js
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage("com.my_company.my_application",
  {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, //  Send those parameters to your program.
  (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }
)
```

### Example repository

I have created a project [thunder/e11fde9](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/tree/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57) whose ultimate goal is to be able to use a browser as input and then open a specified file locally (without a mouse, if possible)

It is still in development, but I think the early code is enough. The link is below.

- [chrome-ext](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/tree/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57/chrome-ext) A test Chrome extension.
- [go](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/tree/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57/go) I built an EXE with [Golang](https://golang.org/) and put it on the [host/bin](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/blob/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57/host/manifest.json#L4) to simulate the local program.
- [host](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/tree/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57/host) Install the schema and specify the program. (see [manifest.json](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/thunder/blob/e11fde9aef3ff59c7e6e9c7119d7c584ff51ef57/host/manifest.json))

Which already has a log that records the results of the browser's transmission, while the browser can also get the program's return value.

### Reference

- [GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/475b4b6/mv2-archive/api/nativeMessaging/host)
  It's useful, and it provides a way to use python to communicate.
- [jfarleyx/chrome-native-messaging-golang](https://github.com/jfarleyx/chrome-native-messaging-golang/blob/95c4d57/native-host/src/main.go)
  use golang to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

I go for hypothesys since I can't verify now.

With Apache, if you make a php script on your local machine calling your executable, and then call this script via POST or GET via html/javascript?

would it function?

let me know.

Comment: Of course this would work if the Apache process had the required permissions, **but what's the point** when  you would then need to install Apache and open webserver ports on the **user's computer**....