# Execute a program from a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The [Google Chrome NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) is being phased out.

Without using NPAPI, is there any way to allow an extension to execute a command on the local system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: The above mentioned possible duplicate isn't as up-to-date as this one. The duplicate talks about using NPAPI which this question is talking about how to replace.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is **[chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendNativeMessage)** which can be used to send a message to a native application and **[chrome.runtime.connectNative](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-connectNative)** which allows for a more persistent connection.

So, you can't directly execute a command, but you can have a native app do it for you.

You can find more info on Native Messaging in **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging)**.

Comment: The links in the solution are not working anymore, please refer to the new url: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/