# Read SSID name inside a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and is there a way to read the SSID name or Network name of the current connection from the code?

Comment: probably not in a OS neutral way

Comment: @JaromandaX any javascript that would read this info at least from Windows?

Comment: I'm not aware of what you can do with chrome extensions as far as running external executables - which is what you would need to do

Comment: "running external executables" is not possible in a Chrome extension. Too bad

Comment: the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917543/execute-a-program-from-a-chrome-extension) may help

Comment: this sheds some light. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no [Chrome Extension APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) that would provide this information.

As suggested in comments, your only option is to have a [Native Host module](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) that would do it for you.