# How to run Grunt Build task by cliking on button through browser?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I have made one build process through grunt and it works fine from command prompt. Now I have a application from where i want to run this task by clicking build button.

So is there any way i can rung grunt task from browser by writing any js or php script?

If any further clarification needed do let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Server-side script - like PHP, Python, etc. that launches your task.
2. A browser plugin that uses native libraries ([Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension)).

Option one is, of course, much easier. And you don't even need a full webstack if you just want to run it without arguments or anything.

Python can be as simple as:

```
import socket
import subprocess

s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM );
s.bind( ( '0.0.0.0', 17777 ) )
s.listen()

while True:
    connection, client_address = soc.accept();
    connection.send( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n' )
    subprocess.call( ['grunt', '..'] )
    connection.close()
```

Then simply hit it, like `<a href="host:17777">run</a>` or an XHR.

For more exotic things, like status reporting, arguments, etc. you'll need something more complex. If you already have a PHP-based stack up, you can simply do something like:

```
<?php
    echo `grunt ...`;
?>
```

This will, of course wait for grunt to finish. So you may look into PHP's [`pcntl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) and the like.

Another idea, if you're using something like [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) or [`ramona`](http://ateska.github.io/ramona/), which have web-based control panels, is to send requests to them so that they can start a grunt process.

So the above should suffice for a tiny use-case, not so flexible. For something more robust, extensible and serious look into [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and other task queues. You can get a quite powerful command and control center using [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for example, along with a task queue. Building one in PHP shouldn't be substantially difficult either.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. it's done with '<?php echo exec('grunt') ?>'

Comment: Note that backticks are execution operators in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [grunt-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-serve) plugin. It seems to do exactly what you're after.