# How to run Grunt task by cliking on button through browser webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have made one build process through grunt and it works fine from command prompt. Now I have a application from where i want to run this task by clicking build button via browser. so, there is any way to do this task by using javascript without using PHP and python.

Comment: With server-side JavaScript via NodeJS.

Comment: You'd need your server to either run grunt via terminal, or try running grunt through a node server.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343331/how-to-run-grunt-build-task-by-cliking-on-button-through-browser