# How to call executable from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to call snippingtool.exe from google chrome extension by using below code but it is not working. Can someone help me with that?

file: manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "Capture and copy whole/part of screen.",
  "version": "0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "path": "C:\\Projects\\Chrome.AddOn.HelloWorld\\Chrome.AddOn.HelloWorld\\SnippingTool.exe",
  "type": "stdio" 
}
```

It gives below error:
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Unrecognized manifest key 'path'.
Unrecognized manifest key 'type'.

Comment: It seems you are mixing up the extension manifest and the Native Host manifest. Those are different files.

Comment: you can't easily do this. see duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension

Comment: NPAPI was outdated since Jan-2014. See this: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html What would be the best alternative to it?

Comment: @KenLiu This has nothing to do with NPAPI. This is about Native Hosts.

Comment: Xan, Would  you able to provide me a solution to implement this?

Comment: Look into Native Messaging. You'll have to alter the native binary to work with it. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging