# URI protocol works in Internet Explorer but not in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, uri, protocol-handler

I followed the instructions in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) microsoft tutorial. and it works great in IE. but when I attempt this in Chrome it just does a search.

Can this be done in Chrome? if so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension