# Launch .exe file using Javascript from IE, Chorome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I know we can launch .exe file using following code snippet. but this only works for IE. My client very often use Chorome and Firefox as well. How can I modify this snippet to launch the exe from other browsers as well.

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var commandtoRun = "C:\User\Desktop\test.exe"; `oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");`
```

Also, there any mean to pass any argument to that opening .exe file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension.

Comment: Additional information: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977261.

Comment: This was answered in post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to have the .exe you want to run register itself with a [custom protocol URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example, lets say you have a program, alert.exe, that will show or send an alert. You could register the URI Scheme `alert`. Then your link would look like:

```
<a href="alert:Message to Show">Alert</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link, the browser will launch your alert.exe and pass the string `Message to Show` to it.

Comment: I've accomplished this thank you for your comment. But you can help me in another way. That is I want to launch .exe file that is located at network and the link to that file is: \\bisco\root\apps\ABC\ABCNavigator\NavLauncher.exe. I tried by changing backslash to double and even with forward slashes but no luck. Can you please provide some clue to reach out to that file.

Comment: Have you tried with the network path mapped to a local drive?

Comment: Maybe try with a mapped drive, map G: to \\bisco\root\apps\ABC\ABCNavigator\ and then change the Scheme command to (Default) = "G:\NavLauncher.exe" "%1"

Answer (score 0):

Could an inline script work?

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/User/Desktop/test.exe')">
```

I'm not sure if you can replicate this on Firefox or Chrome because of security issues.

These links may be helpful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Running_applications

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi