# Can I use Chrome's native messaging API in an extension to open a local HTML file in my default text editor (eg. Sublime Text)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm just getting started with Chrome extensions and I was wondering if this is feasible.

I'll often navigate to a local HTML file and open it up for viewing in Chrome. I'd like to be able to click an extension's icon to automatically take that local file URL and open up the file in a text editor installed on my computer (like Sublime Text for example).

As some commenters have pointed out, [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension) was asked 6 years ago. The accepted answer is deprecated today, but a more up-to-date answer (3 years ago) cites the native messaging API as a possible solution.

I'm hoping someone with a great understanding of it can tell me whether or not my end goal here is possible using this tech.

Comment: Only if it was downloaded in Chrome. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-open

Comment: Well, you can register a [custom protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059878) or make a nativeMessaging host utility that will be able to do anything.

Comment: @Makyen That question is sadly massively outdated.

Comment: @Xan, Then that older question should receive new answers detailing how solutions should be accomplished now. At an absolute minimum, the OP should have done some searching to find other potential answers. This Question should contain an explanation why any other (obvious/easily found) duplicate questions are not duplicates and/or why such solutions presented as answers to those questions are not working/acceptable in the current situation. Alternately, a bounty can be posted on the duplicate question asking for more current answers.

Comment: @Makyen The problem with such question is that they have massively upvoted answers that overshadow newer answers, and the OP usually doesn't answer to requests to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Xan, The OP should not change the accepted answer. The [acceptance indicates that it is the solution which the OP actually used to solve *their* problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It does not indicate the best current solution. Yes, new, current/better solutions can take considerable time (even years) to migrate up to similar levels of up-votes. That is part of how Stack Exchange works. An additional thing you can do is to leave comments to the effect that the solution is no longer works on older answers which you have tried and found to no longer be functional.