# start an external application from a Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

How can we start an external application(exe) from a chrome browser?

I have gone through this link which says we can open it from a chrome extension: 
[Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension) as I have found few extensions which when installed starts my external exe(application).

However, I would like to open the application directly from chrome without any extension.

Is it possible? Is Native Messaging something to look in that case?

Comment: nativeMessaging is an API for extensions so the answer is no.

Comment: oh okay, so is it possible to write any piece of code directly in the web application(the one which should invoke the exe) which would enable the same

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. :)